# javax.mail.MessagingException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected

Tags: jakarta-mail, exchange-server, office365

I am trying to read mail from exchange server using IMAP protocol. I have implemented the code. But following exception occurs while executing the code.This exception occurs occasionally, I didn't get the reason why this is happening.

javax.mail.MessagingException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:958)
    at agent.client.attributeGroups.SendReceive.readMailAndReply(SendReceive.java:115)
    at agent.client.attributeGroups.MailQueue.calculateTime(MailQueue.java:45)
    at agent.client.MainClass$1.run(MainClass.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.imap.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.imap.host", "outlook.office365.com");
            props.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "imap");  
            props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", true);
            props.put("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", true);
            props.put("mail.imap.auth.gssapi.disable", true);

          //Get session object by passing credentials.
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(
                                    mailId, mailPass);}});

         //Creating IMAP store and connecting it to Mailbox using credentials.   
         store = session.getStore("imap");
         store.connect(mailId, mailPass);

             //Getting mailbox mails.
             inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
             inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE); 
             int totalMailCount = inbox.getMessageCount();

             //Reading all mails to Message array.
             Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(1, totalMailCount);
             for (Message mail : messages) 
             {  
                    Address[] fromAddresses = mail.getFrom();                      
                    String mailFrom = fromAddresses[0].toString();
                    String mailSubject = mail.getSubject();
                System.out.println(mailFrom);
                    System.out.println(mailSubject);
                    mail.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED,true);

                   }                       
                }

             }
```

Please suggest me suggestions to resolve this exception.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was because I use a process to move emails from inbox to another different folder. I did it in batches because move big quantities emails throw Timeout exception, so I try to move small cquantities and I avoid the Timeout exception but started to get the BadCommandException: A2 BAD User is authenticated but not connected Exception. So I looking by an amount that worked for me. I got the idea base on this post
https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap/issues/689

1. It is a Microsoft's mechanism to shut down chatty clients. The
   solution would be to login to this account less frequently.
2. It is due to a bug in the IMAP implementation. If the client presents a valid user name but an invalid password, the server
   accepts the login, but subsequent commands fail with the
   aforementioned error message.
3. It is a shared mailbox and you are using incorrect login scheme. Use Username@DomainName\SharedMailboxAlias for O365

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced that issue
You didn't close the connection,it always in open.

If you use Store and Inbox it always authenticated but not connected 
It is authentication successfully but not connected because session is paradise.

You need to add below lines to your code.

First close the inbox after read

**inbox.close(true);**

Next close the store Connection

**store.close();**

If you close the estabilished connection correctly then it will connected according to the session.

Hope this really helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

This error message appears to be triggered when you've connected to an Exchange mail server (such as Office365) with a valid user and the correct password, but that user doesn't have permissions for the type of connection you made.

For example, I've seen several cases now where an IMAP connection was made, the system logged in with valid credentials, and the moment the first IMAP command was sent, the server said, "User is authenticated but not connected" and closed the connection.

To correct it, we went into the Exchange server or Office365 mail settings and ensured that the IMAP permission was checked for that user.

Answer (score 1):

- First,you should check the mail.imap.host value is equivalent to the email address's server.
  [If you use outlook OC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJR4f.png)
- If true,you could then try to change the protocol to **`IMAPS`**

I hope the snippets that set of properties can help many that want to recieve mails.

```
    sysProperties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", true);
    MailSSLSocketFactory sf = null;
    try {
        sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);

    sysProperties.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
    sysProperties.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");

    sysProperties.put("mail.imap.ssl.socketFactory", sf);
    sysProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.port", instance.getConfigPropertiesValue(configProperties, "mail.imap.port"));
    sysProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.socketFactory.port", "993");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(sysProperties, null);

    Store store = null;
    store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("mail.serverhost", "mail.serverport"),  "mail.username,"mail.password"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to your exchange settings? I ran into this error with imap and outlook.office365.com.  I tried to set up the same account in Outlook to make sure it was working in general.  Although I was able to add the account, when I actually tried to look at the inbox Outlook became unresponsive.  So in my case, it was a problem with the account in general, not with how I was trying to connect.

Answer (score -1):

It appears to be a [bug in the office365 server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164823/user-is-authenticated-but-not-connected-after-changing-my-exchange-password).  It's telling you that your password was wrong.

Comment: I don't think so password is wrong, because this exception occurs occasionally. All other time it's execute fine.

Comment: Try fixing [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) #1 and #4 and see if that helps.